# bash - why does ( cd && sleep 5000 ) start second process

Tags: bash, sleep, pid

I have this script test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
( cd . && sleep 5000 )
```

I execute with `./test.sh &`
and then run `ps lax | grep test.sh`

I now have 2 processes running...

```
0  1000  6883  6600  20   0  10600  1332 -      S    pts/2      0:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
1  1000  6884  6883  20   0  10604   704 -      S    pts/2      0:00 /bin/bash ./test.sh
```

- Why do I have two processes running and where does the second process come from?
- Why don't I have two processes if I remove the `cd ".."` from the command?

Thanks for any explanation, I just don't get it and I think I'm lacking some basics here... or is this some vodoo? ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Grouping a series of bash commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Command-Grouping) inside parenthesis will execute them in a sub-shell.

Comment: I didn't notice that this answer came 1 mins before my post. :) removed mine and +1 yours.

Answer (score 0):

Writing two commands together might pose some difficulties for Terminal to detect the commands. Perhaps you could split it up into 2 commands.

```
cd ...

sleep 5000
```

Comment: There is no difficulty. Parentheses for a subshell, and `ps` is reporting both processes. Executing a command line this is useful for when you want to temporarily change the working directory without worrying about changing back to the original working directory.